# Pycurl giving me errors saying object doesnt have curl

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

Below is my code with some mods to it because it contained passwords and such. But when i run this code it get a error saying (AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Curl'). I tried looking for this and cant find a working method, so how would I fix this?

```
 #buy cloud hashing
cloudhash = input('Do you want to buy cloud hashing?: ')
print('You choose', cloudhash)
if cloudhash == "yes":
    print("You chose to buy hashing power")
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://www.eobot.com/api.aspx?id=45723&email=Joshman160@*******.com&password=**********&convertfrom=DOGE&amount=20.0&convertto=KHS')
    c.perform()

else:
    print("You Choose not to buy hashing power")
```

Comment: did you name your file/package `pycurl` by any chance?

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: What do you mean package. Im new to python. I tried to follow the first code section from http://www.angryobjects.com/2011/10/15/http-with-python-pycurl-by-example/

Comment: what is the name of the python file you are executing this code from ?

Comment: Can you post the _full_ traceback... that should contain the file name of the script.

Comment: you have  `pycurl` somewhere that is not the module.

Comment: how would i get that in the modual. or use this url https://www.eobot.com/api.aspx?id=1&email=support@eobot.com&password=PASSWORD&convertfrom=BTC&amount=1.0&convertto=GHS to buy hashing then.

Comment: when you `import pycurl` and `print pycurl.__file__ `what do you see?

Comment: I found out what my issue was. Pycurl did not install correctly for some reason. It is now working like a dream .